# FlashBuilder 4.5 issue: "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: "

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm seeing an issue a few times now using FlashBuilder 4.5. First I create a new ActionScript Project, then add a Library Project's bin folder to the build path, and reference the Library Project. I code the new project, and everything works fine. But later, when I'm optimizing the code, I'll create a new ActionScript class file in the Library Project, save it, and then change an already defined function within the ActionScript Project to use this new ActionScript class in the Library Project instead of some other class in the Library Project. The class file is in the Library Project's src folder, under (default package), same as all the other files the ActionScript Project is using successfully.

At this point, FlashBuilder shows an error "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: PEArrays."

Here is the Library Project file:

```
package 
{
    public class PEArrays
    {
        public var x:Array;  
        public var y:Array;
        public var o:Array;
    }
}
```

I have included `import PEArrays;` or, `import PEArrays.*;` and both result in the same error.

Also, I tried exiting and re-entering FlashBuilder, didn't help.

Cleaning the ActionScript Project had no effect on this error. I also right-clicked on the project folder and selected Refresh, but it didn't help.

I verified that the needed classes are correctly selected by going to Project>Properties>Flex Library Build Path and reviewing the Classes tab. I'm just a single developer so there's no version control system in place.

After troubleshooting a bit, I now find that the ActionScript Project folder's bin directory is empty. When I run the .as file in the ActionScript Project's src folder, I get an error that the ASname.html file cannot be found (where ASname is the ActionScript Project name and also the .as file name, e.g. ASname.as, in the src folder, which is run). This ASname.html file is not found in the html-template folder. What process generates this needed .html file? Can I manually trigger it somehow?

[other ActionScript Projects I have that depend on this Library Project run fine, although the PEArrays class in question is not used]

Here are some similar postings.

[FlashBuilder workspace update issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151034/flashbuilder-workspace-update-issues)
[Flash Builder keeps losing my imported classes...arghh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545466/flash-builder-keeps-losing-my-imported-classes-arghh)

Comment: The class file is in the Library Project's src folder, under (default package), same as all the other files the ActionScript Project is using successfully.

Comment: From what I can tell from Google, that checkbox is for Mobile applications. When running as "Web Application", which I'm doing, there doesn't appear to be launch settings for one to select this checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I don't know what caused the problem, but I found one solution:

1. export all the projects (each to a separate file)
2. create a new directory structure on the hard drive
3. use Flash Builder 4.5 to import these files into the new directory structure.

When I first tried this things failed the same way. Then I realized that I needed to update the Library Project's path to the new hard drive directories. After doing that, the errors went away. Thus,

`4`. in each ActionScript (or Flex) Project, open the Properties tab, click on ActionScript Build Path, remove the old Build path for the Library Project, and add SWC folder for the new path.

Seems like Flash Builder gets stuck in a bad state every now and again.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your new Class didn't get compiled in.  One of two things has happened.

1. Your Class isn't checked in Project>Properties>Flex Library Build Path
2. .flexLibProperties isn't writable (this can happen under some version control systems)

Check out http://www.developria.com/2010/12/tips-for-working-with-library.html for more information.

Comment: Hi Amy, I verified that the class was checked already by going to Project>Properties>Flex Library Build Path and reviewing the Classes tab. I'm just a single developer so there's no version control system in place. Currently there is nothing in the bin folder for the Library Project, or the bin-debug folder for the ActionScript Project. I don't know how to generate the files in there. When I attempt to run the AS Project, I get an error that it can't find an html file in the bin folder. The code itself reports it doesn't find the PEArrays.as file in the Project Folder.

Comment: Try deleting the contents of your bin and bin-debug folders, then cleaning the projects again.

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, I never trust FlashBuilder "Build Automatically": it slows down performance of the application (because nearly every change causes a re-build.) Disable "Build Automatically", and memorize the keyboard command to Build.

When you use "Clean..", use "Clean Projects Selected Below" and highlight the specific projects. There've been buggy issues with "Clean all projects".

Last, if you have to, manually clean out your bin folder, and re-build your project.

Comment: I tried cleaning projects one by one and it had no effect. Then I built each manually. But, the bin-debug folders are empty for both Library and ActionScript projects. When I run debug, I get error saying there's no html file in the bin folder.

Comment: The html comes from your html-template. Manually copy those over from html-template. bin-debug and bin-release are generated during build by both copying files over from html-template, as well as compiled versions of your code (i.e. swf, swc, etc.)

Comment: The ActionScript project name is ASname, for the sake of discussion. The ActionScript file that executes when running the project is ASname.as. When I run to debug the project, the error I get is: File not found: path/ASname.html. When I look in the html-template directory, I only find index.template.html, playerProductInstall.swf, and swfobject.js. What would cause ASname.html not to be included in the html-template directory?

Comment: Select Project -> Export Release Build.... Put into the bin-release folder. Copy-paste Aname.html from that folder into bin-debug. Delete the bin-release folder.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, when I try that I get the error: "One or more errors were found while trying to build the release version. Unable to export. See details for more information." The Details window lists all the original errors related to the title of this question "Type was not found..." in each place that PEArrays is used in file ASname.as. While the bin-release directory is created, nothing is inside it.

Comment: Back to square one. Just include the class inside your main "src" folder, build Release Build (bin-release), should give you your files, including that ASname.html, that you can copy into your bin-debug. Delete the main "src" folder, and now do a manual build.